# Permission error in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I gave the `READ_SMS` as well as `READ_CALL_LOG` permission in manifest file but still I am getting `SecurityException` in my `BroadcastReceiver`.

**Code:**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    getMissedCallCount(context);
    getUnreadSMSCount(context);
}

private void getMissedCallCount(Context context) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d("Call Logs permission", "Not provided...");
        return;
    }
    String[] projection = {CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, CallLog.Calls.TYPE};
    String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" + CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE;
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, where, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    Log.d("CALL COUNT: ", ""+c.getCount());
    c.close();
}
```

**Log:**

`Call Logs permission: Not provided...`

Any idea about this problem?

Comment: Provide not READ_SMS but READ_CALL_LOG permission in manifest (you've added read_sms permission in manifest, but in runtime check read_call_log permission, got it? There permissions are of different groups). And if you need READ_SMS permission, then you should request it: 
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: I gave both the permissions. Please see my edited question.

Comment: @Satheshkumar read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html) completely.

Comment: @maveň Thanks for the link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: @Satheshkumar [READ_CALL_LOG](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_CALL_LOG) & [READ_SMS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_SMS) both have different usage and role they are meant for. you have only used READ_CALL_LOG permission ... adding permission to  manifest won't work for api>23

Comment: @maveň 'adding permission to manifest won't work for api>23' This gave me the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

## Check For Permissions:

```
// Assume thisActivity is the current activity
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
```

The following code checks if the app has permission to read the user's contacts, and

## Requests the permission if necessary:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_SMS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_SMS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

[official google doc](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) & [complete blog](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/17/random-musings-android-6p0-sdk.html)